# Como fazer algo expirar apos certos meses na db?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu quero adicionar uma "licença" para uma compra na minha database, mais essa licença que o meu "cliente" irá comprar terá um prazo de expiração, vamos dizer que ele comprou uma licença...

```
    INSERT INTO compras (userid, pluginid) VALUES ('$userid', '$pluginid');
```

Agora, eu quero fazer com que esse INSERT que eu fiz se apague daqui a 1 mês, por exemplo, como faço isso??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faça esta deleção , crie uma coluna DATA_DE_VALIDADE , na aplicação teste algo como

```
select *
from compras
where userid = 'DaviDEV'
and   CURDATE() <= DATA_DE_VALIDADE
```

A vantagem é não se perde a informação permitindo até "correr atrás" do cliente para um retorno.

Comment: Mais na hora de fazer o INSERT, o que eu preencho no campo DATA_DE_VALIDADE?

Comment: Algo como ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY) , ou seja a data de quando "caduca" a compra. No caso 31 dias da data corrente.

Comment: Tipo:
    INSERT INTO compras (userid, pluginid,expiracao) VALUES ('$userid', '$pluginid',ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY));
??????

Comment: Sim, mas a coluna precisa existir na tabela , para isto veja ADD COLUMN emhttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: eu acho a sugestão do Motta melhor, nunca se deve descartar um histórico de compra de um cliente. até porque, se acontecer de seu sistema fornecer um mesmo numero de licença de um cliente que já a comprou, você pode se complicar

Comment: Não, estou usando so para absorver conhecimento, não tenho loja virtual nem algo do tipo.

Comment: então encare apenas como boas práticas!

Answer (score 3):

dê uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940039/mysql-insertworking-with-expiration-date) do SO.

```
now() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

enquanto NOW retorna a atual data e hora, INTERVAL adiciona um intervalo de tempo, veja no manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html